# NSubstitute mock a void method with out parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I am new to NSubstitute, I am trying to mock a `void` method with 2 `out` parameters and I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong.

I have a `CustomerDataAccess` class that has a method with the following signature:

```
void GetCustomerWithAddresses(int customerId, 
                              out List<Customer> customers, 
                              out List<Address> addresses);
```

The `CustomerRepository` calls its `GetCustomer` method which then calls the `CustomerDataAccess.GetCustomerWithAddresses` DAL method. The DAL method then outputs two `out` parameters one for the customer and one for addresses. The repository method then uses `AutoMapper` to map the two objects from the DAL method to a business domain which the repository then returns.

Here is the code I have so far and it is not working. My research hasn't helped me to identify what I need to do to fix this issue.  How do I set the value of my `out` parameters?

```
// Arange
ICustomerDataAccess customerDataAccess = Substitute.For<ICustomerDataAccess>();
IList<Customer> customers;
IList<Address> addresses;

customerDataAccess.When(x => x.GetCustomerWithAddresses(
    1, out customers, out addresses))
    .Do(x =>
    {
        customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "John Doe" } };
        addresses = new List<Address>() { new Address() { AddressId = 1, AddressLine1 = "123 Main St", City = "Atlanta" } };
    });

CustomerRepository sut = new CustomerRepository(customerDataAccess);

// Act
Customer customer = sut.GetCustomer(1);

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(customer);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`out` parameters are updated using their parameter position as an index.  It's explained in the `Returns` [documentation for NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/setting-out-and-ref-arguments/).  So, for your particular case, you are populating the second and third parameters, so you should be setting up your call like this:

```
customerDataAccess.When(x => x.GetCustomerWithAddresses(1, out customers, out addresses))
.Do(x =>
{
    x[1] = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "John Doe" } };
    x[2] = new List<Address>() { new Address() { AddressId = 1, AddressLine1 = "123 Main St", City = "Atlanta" } };
});
```

Comment: Yep that worked i was missing accessing the specific parameters in the array.

Answer (score 3):

For non-void methods the regular return syntax can be used:

```
 var haveWithAddresses = customerDataAccess.GetCustomerWithAddresses(1, out customers, out addresses)
               .Returns(callInfo => { 
                     callInfo[0] = new List<Customer>();
                     callInfo[1] = new List<Address>();
                     return true;
               });
```

With `Void` methods the `When...Do` syntax is correct.